# Auto Add Row When Click a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables in two tabs (tab hasilproduksi and tab downtime). Each tab is a page with a table. I want to add a row to the table when I click the plus button. My code does not work as expected.

[tab_hasilproduksi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AXqr.jpg)

[image]

[tab_donwtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYZys.jpg)

[image]

**here is my code** (tab_hasilproduksi):

```
function addTableRowHasilProduksi() {
    row = parseInt($('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val()) + 1;
    $('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').remove();
    var html = ' \
    <tr id="rowTableHasilProduksi_' + row + '"> \
      <td> \
        <div class="input-group"> \
            <input id="typepartid_' + row + '" class="form-control ui-autocomplete" type="text" onchange="myFunction(' + row + ')" name="typepartid_' + row + '"  >\
            <span class="input-group-btn">\
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" name="button" id="buttonPartID' + row + '">\
            </button>\
            </span>\
                    </div>\
      </td> \
     <td>\
        <select id="hasilproduksi_' + row + '" class="form-control" onchange="hasilProduksiChage(' + row + ')" name="hasilproduksi_' + row + '"> \
          <option value="-">--Select--</option>\
          <option value="Good">Good</option>\
          <option value="Repair">Repair</option>\
          <option value="Reject">Reject</option>\
        </select> \
      </td> \
      <td><input id="qty_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control"  onkeydown="return numbersonly(this, event);" onkeyup="javascript:tandaPemisahTitik(this);" name="qty_' + row + '" /> \
      </td> \
      <td id="tdTypeReject_' + row + '"> \
        <select id="typereject_' + row + '" class="form-control" name="typereject_' + row + '"> \
        ' + htmlTypeReject + ' \
        </select> \
      </td> \
      <td><input id="keteranganreject_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="keteranganreject_' + row + '"/></td> \
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="deleteRowHasilProduksi(' + row + ')">x</button></td> \
    </tr> \
    <tr id="plusButtonHasilProduksi"> \
      <td colspan="6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="width:100%" onclick="addTableRowHasilProduksi()">+</button></td> \
    </tr>';
    $('#tableHasilProduksi > tbody').append(html);
    //variable row table add +1
    $('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val(row);

}
```

tab_downtime :

```js
function addTableRowDowntime() {
  row = parseInt($('#tableRowDowntime').val()) + 1;
  $('#plusButtonDowntime').remove();
  var html = ' \
    <tr id="rowTableDowntime_' + row + '"> \
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="deleteRowDowntime(' + row + ')">-</button></td> \
    <td><input id="partdown_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="partdown_' + row + '" readonly="readonly"></input>\</td> \
      <td id="tdDowntime_' + row + '"> \
        <select id="downtime_' + row + '" class="form-control" name="downtime_' + row + '"> \
        ' + htmlDowntime + ' \
        </select> \
      </td> \
      <td><input id="durasi_' + row + '" class="form-control" type="text" name="durasi_' + row + '" onfocusout="durasiOnFocusOut(this)" onfocusin="durasiOnFocusIn(this)"/></td> \
      <td><input id="keterangandowntime_' + row + '" class="form-control" type="text" name="keterangandowntime_' + row + '"/></td> \
    </tr> \
    <tr id="plusButtonDowntime"> \
      <td colspan="5"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="width:100%" onclick="addTableRowDowntime()">+</button></td> \
    </tr>';
  $('#tableDowntime > tbody').append(html);
  //variable row table add +1
  $('#tableRowDowntime').val(row);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for?

Comment: i want to if i click plus button in tab Hasil Produksi, automatically add row in tab Downtime too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a global counter like `var cnt = 0;`, this will keep the number of times add button is clicked in `tab_hasilproduksi`.

```
var cnt = 0;
function addTableRowHasilProduksi() {
  ...
  ...
  //variable row table add +1
  $('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val(row);
  cnt++;
}
```

Once you swtich the tab to `tab_downtime` (you need to check on a conditional basis)

```
for(var i=0; i<cnt; i++){
  addTableRowDowntime();
}
```

Call `addTableRowDowntime()` inside the loop.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: when i put addTableRowDowntime() at the end of the addTableRowHasilProduksi function, in tab downtime automatically add one row eventhough i haven't clicked yet. for example : tab_hasilproduksi by default is one row but after i add this code, in tab_downtime by default is 2 rows

Comment: @SandhiZukhrufZusiarta I have updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: the result is same with your code before. in tab downtime automatically add one row eventhough i haven't clicked yet. for example : tab_hasilproduksi by default is one row but after i add this code, in tab_downtime by default is 2 rows

Comment: @SandhiZukhrufZusiarta . I'm sure that you have kept the `loop` code in wong location. Can you create a jsfiddle with your code (even it's not executing is fine).

Comment: Thanks for creating a fiddle. Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/qk4sgg1y/1/ . Check the line 40 onwards. If you can add `HTML` code, then I can give you exact solution.

Comment: your code doesn't work. when i click plus button, table in tab downtime doesn't add row automatically

Comment: How you will come to know whether a row has been added or not unless you visit 'Downtime' tab?

Comment: i have visited tab downtime and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an event listener on click of the `+` button? If so it should be simple, just call your `addTableRowDowntime()` function in event listener, something like:

`$('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').on('click', function() {
    addTableRowDowntime();
});`

Comment: you can add it in your `addTableRowHasilProduksi()` function, but if `addTableRowHasilProduksi` is being called on click of plus button already then there is no need to add event listener, you can just call `addTableRowDowntime()` at the end of the `addTableRowHasilProduksi` function

Comment: when i put addTableRowDowntime() at the end of the addTableRowHasilProduksi function, in tab downtime automatically add i row eventhough i haven't clicked yet. for example : tab_hasilproduksi by default is one row but after i add this code, in tab_downtime by default is 2 rows

Comment: do you know what function is called on click of `plusButtonHasilProduksi` button currently? if no, you can try adding the event listener to the beginning of `addTableRowHasilProduksi` function and see what happens.

Comment: when i remove $('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').remove(); and change with your code. it doesn't work. any idea?